# trouble with a javafx menu style

Tags: java, javafx, menuitem

can someone tell me how i can fix this padding/shadow like effect around my MenuItems?
I dont know the Name of it so a research was hard without an exact name of it:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/901/GyPRgA.png

This gradient isn't part of my stage background its a background  which opens with the Menu like a Container holding the Menu.

Sorry guys its hard to explain hopefully you can help me.

The screenshot i cant post fully since i got only  1 reputation so i add a link to it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since i was playing around trying to figure my problem while waiting i felt onto the solution for it.

For those which have the same Problem:
Solution:
Since the new Modena style is used by default, the context menu's are styled with a drop shadow / Gaussian blur effect, which made when opening the Menu it gave some kind of strange effect when using an other background on the stage.

To solve this its only needed to overwrite(resetting) the style..
in my case it was the follow one which i needed to overwrite in a new css file.

-fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) , 12, 0.0 , 0 , 8 );